# How to get img.naturalWidth in Angular 6 Directive?

Tags: angular6, angular2-directives

I have a custom Angular 6 directive like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appImgOrientation]'
})
export class ImgOrientationDirective {

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {   
      console.log(el);
      console.log(el.nativeElement);
  }

}
```

`el` returns the element with all of its properties. `el.nativeElement` has many properties. (50+)

But `el.nativeElement` returns only the elements html code:

```
<img _ngcontent-c2 src="https://example.com/image.jpg" class="MyClass">
```

I want to read `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties of `nativeElement`. I can already read these values using native Javascript on `<img (load)="detectOrientation(imgUrl)">` but I don't want to.

```
detectOrientation(imgUrl): void {
      var orientation;
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = imgUrl;

      img.onload = () => {
        if (img.naturalWidth > img.naturalHeight) {
          //landscape
          orientation = 'h';
        } else if (img.naturalWidth < img.naturalHeight) {
          // portrait
          orientation = 'v';
        } else {
          // even
          orientation = 'square';
        }
}
```

I want to do it in the directive. How can I do it?

Comment: I also invovled the same issue. el.nativeElement.naturalWidth will get 0 due to img is still loading when code run in ngafterViewInit(){}. have to wait img finish load to get its height or width

Answer (score 0):

Although logging el.nativeElement prints the html markup to console, this object does in fact have accessible properties, as listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Example:

```
console.log(el.nativeElement.naturalWidth);
```